# Garbage data generator to fill hard disk storage

Tags: c#, file, storage

Even if  we delete data from the hard disk or storage of mobile phone, there is a chance to retrieve the data.

I want to completely erase the data as I sell my laptop/mobile phone.

I thought to create a garbage data generator in C# by creating a text file with some dummy text. And I will write the sample text until it grow like 10 GB. So if I fill my laptop or mobile phone with this file, I guess no one can retrieve my personal files.
This will work or am I crazy ?

Comment: Is this a question of how/if this can work or how can you do it in c#? I'd close as duplicate of this Q&A if it wasn't another Stack: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49166/is-filling-up-the-empty-space-in-a-disk-with-any-data-enough-measure-against-fil

Comment: It depends if you have a **hard** disc or a **flash** storage / **ssd**

Answer (score 1):

Typically speaking, overwritten data cannot be recovered. After all, there is something else where it used to be and this isn't like in a notebook where you use Tipex to cover the original text and write on top.

Be careful though, unless you really fill it in completely one can still find fragments of the old data.

Answer (score 1):

We pretty much have two different types of storage devices and they are different.

## Solid State Drives

The modern drives, found in all phones and many computers. One over-write should be enough. Writing too many times could crash the drive immediately (I've crashed a few).

## Mechanical Hard Drives

These require multiple writes. 1-3 layers is easy to recover and with a lab you can recover a minimum of 10 layers. Governments and large enterprises typically destroy them instead.

Comment: When you overwrite a file on a SSD then the internal controller of the drive will store them at a complete different "physical" location on the drive. The old data is physically **not** overwritten because of the internal save strategy

Comment: When you overwrite a file on a mechanical hard drive, in most cases the old physical locations are reused. Modern drives will overwrite the whole magnetic information. On old (very old) drives you could restore the old magnetic information.

Comment: Read https://www.howtogeek.com/234683/why-you-cant-securely-delete-a-file-and-what-to-do-instead/

Comment: @SirRufo so, if I own a 120 GB SSD, and write 120 GB of data to it twice, it will be stored in different locations because it is actually a 10000 TB SSD but the size is hidden?

Comment: @SirRufo have you figured out a way to make all the 10000 TB on the SSD usable at once?

Comment: @SirRufo Yes. I have the same query asked by Mikael Dúi Bolinder

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder

Comment: @SirRufo Just forget the big amount. Suppose, an SSD is 1GB. I generate a file sized 1 GB. I have written the file to this SSD, can I get the old data back...? This is magic or technology ? :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I **explicit** mentioned a **file** which will be overwritten. Your answer is not clear if you want to overwrite a file or the entire disk. If you write random data to files which will fill up the **whole** disk, then old data is overwritten because you have written to every physical location.